# Parsing underscore delimited fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing, mysql-workbench, string-parsing

I have the following table:

```
Patent      AssigneeName                        AssigneeUnparsed
-------     --------------                      ---------------
D452605     Louis Vuitton Malletier, S.A.       Paris_None_FR
D452606     Nike, Inc.                          Beaverton_OR_US
D452607     Salomon S.A.                        Metz-Tessy_None_FR
```

I have searched the site and cant find anything specific on how to explain parsing an underscored field into separate fields.  I want to take the AssigneeAddress field and parse it into three fields (AssigneeCity, AssigneeState, AssigneeCountry)

Can someone explain how to do this or point me to a tutorial so I can attempt to figure it out?

Comment: Have you looked through the set of MySQL string functions?  Your answer lies there. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

Comment: AssigneeAddress is always composed by three fields, or there can be more (or less)?

Comment: Does my answer work for you? Just do an update with the substring_index and that should take care of it for you. Lookup substirng_index for more info on the syntax SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count).

Comment: fthiella, looks like yes, always 2 underscores given the 'None' notation.

Comment: Yea its always 3 fields into one... I inherited the dataset and its quite annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    substring_index('Beaverton_OR_US', '_', - 1) as AssigneeCity,
    substring_index(substring_index('Beaverton_OR_US', '_', 2),
            '_',
            - 1) as AssigneeState,
    substring_index('Beaverton_OR_US', '_', 1) as AssigneeCountry;
```

Update :

```
update tablename 
set 
    AssigneeCity = substring_index('Beaverton_OR_US', '_', - 1),
    AssigneeState = substring_index(substring_index('Beaverton_OR_US', '_', 2),
            '_',
            - 1),
    AssigneeCountry = substring_index('Beaverton_OR_US', '_', 1);
```

Comment: I see how this works when I run it, but how would the syntax be for me to do this with 2 million records, and insert it into the fields... or is that a different question altogether?

Comment: Be it 1 record or million records, the query is the same. You are not inserting, but updating records if I get this right. All you must be doing is an 'update' operation. Updating my answer.

Comment: wouldnt that do it just for that record, or all records?

Comment: It does it for all records in the table. First add those Assignee(City, State, Country) columns and then update. If you are new to MySQL, a very quick MySQL intro should get you started. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/